# How this code works? (jQuery chaining)

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

I got this code from the jQuery plugin tutorial. however, my question is a `javascript/jquery` question.

In the code you can see that the `filter()` returns an object, which contains a collection of the "filtered" objects. and the `append()` is manipulating it.

What i ask is: how the append function manipulates ALL of the elements and not working only once on the returned object?

```
this.filter( "a" ).append(function() {
   return " (" + this.href + ")";
});
```

Comment: You're question doesn't make much sense. In the second paragraph you said the return object contains the collection … so "ALL of the elements" and "the returned object" are the same thing.

Comment: i understand.. i'll try to rephrase.

Comment: If I've understood what you're asking (literally how it works), it's a question of scope. Per the docs - http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function - `append.function()` operates on "each element in the set of matched elements [...] Within the function, `this` refers to the current element in the set." In other words, in your code, the scope of the initial `this.filter` is different to that of `this.href` within the function itself, which represents each element in turn during the iteration through the collection.

Comment: thank you @fridge_light -  seems you understood what i asked. and answered it. thanks again. (please add it as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the nature of `append(function)` and the difference in scope between the initial `this` and the one inside the function in your code.

Per the jQuery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function, `append(function)` operates on "each element in the set of matched elements. [...] Within the function, `this` refers to the current element in the set."

So, in your code, `this.filter("a")` is a jQuery object containing any matching elements, while `this.href` within the function itself represents each of those elements in turn during the iteration through the collection. Hence, the text is appended to all of the matching elements.